# Embedding pdf at web page

Tags: html

I tried embedding pdf file at my page as:

```html
    <div>
        <object data="/test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
            alt: <a href="test.pdf">test.pdf</a>
        </object>
    </div>
    <embed type="application/pdf"
       src="/test.pdf#toolbar=0"
       width="250"
       height="200">
```

But neither `object` nor `embed` worked, I got my page as:
[image]

Comment: Try a different browser.

Comment: Why don't you just `<iframe>` the PDF? Most browsers can view PDFs without downloading them.

Comment: Keep in mind that `/` is the root directory. It might look for the PDF file at the path `D:/test.pdf`, not in `D:/go/pdf/test.pdf` where it might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason, it has to be run from a server, not working from a file
I'd the below simple go server, and it worked perfectly

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)

    log.Println("Listening on :3000...")
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```